# Why does angular use closures to define directives and other core syntax?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is the advantage of having to write this:

```
app.directive("drink", function () {
  return {
    scope: {
      flavor: "="
    },
    template: '<div>{{ flavor }}</div>'
  };
});
```

Rather than:

```
app.directive("drink", {
    scope: {
      flavor: "="
    },
    template: '<div>{{ flavor }}</div>'
}};
```

This syntax is used all over in angular. What is the reason for it?

Edit: From https://thinkster.io/egghead/isolate-scope-eq

Comment: Your second snippet is invalid JavaScript (*SyntaxError: expected expression, got ','*). `scope:` is interpreted as a label, but `template:` cannot because of the comma in-between.

Comment: So you can only have one label per scope in Javascript?

Comment: You can have several, but then there should be a semicolon before `template:` instead of a comma, and the expression would still not result in a object literal (which seems to be what you're looking for).

Comment: Interesting. http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/17820/  So one results in a function that when executed, returns an object literal. And the other?

Comment: The other sees three labels and two statement blocks, evaluates two strings and returns `undefined`. That's all a matter of syntax, the parser never sees an objet literal in the second snippet.

Comment: This is valid. http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/17827/ It returns undefined, though I'm still trying to understand why

Comment: I can understand that, but still, the second example makes no real sense. I think you first need to harden your syntax skills.

Comment: @Yoshi  Modified the question. http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/17829/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With first example angular has control over when the configuration object gets created, and thus can choose an oportune time. Also it allows for dependency injection in the form of:

```
app.directive("drink", ['drinkStoreService', function (drinkStoreService) {
  return {
    scope: {
      flavor: "="
    },
    template: '<div>{{ flavor }}</div>',

    link: function () {
      // could use `drinkStoreService` here
    }
  };
}]);
```

While your second example has none of the above features. And thus is much less usable. Also, because the object literal will be *"created/exectued on the spot"* it could even be harmful to the program flow.

Comment: Thank you! You're helping me fill in some of my .... "but why??!" questions with angular :)

Answer (score 0):

Also note that by returning a function you can also do something like:

```
   return function()
    {
      var privateVar = mysteriousDataSource(); //Without having this executed instantly

      return {
        scope: {
          flavor: "=",
          mysteriousData : privateVar
        },
        template: '<div>{{ flavor }}</div>'
      };
    }
```